# how to compute subgradient of p-norm, $1 \leq p \leq \infty$

Tags: normed-spaces, subgradient

I am a graduate student in Communications Engineering and I have an optimization course. I need help in solving my assignments: this one is related to convex optimization.
 
We are asked to compute the subgradient for some problems, thus I wanna know how to compute the subgradient of the $p$-norm $\|\mathbf{x}\|_p$.
I know that the subgradient of a function at point $\mathbf{x}$ can be found by solving the condition
$$
f(\mathbf{z})\geq f(\mathbf{x})+\mathbf{g^T(z-x)}.
$$
Since this function has not any gradient at $x=0$, we aim to find subgradient at this point. After putting $\mathbf{x}=0$, I have $\|\mathbf{z}\|_p\geq\mathbf{g^Tz}$. But I don't know how to solve the last equation: how should I proceed?

Comment: Take the set of limits of the gradient of the $p-$norm taken at points where it is differentiable.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950226/how-can-i-prove-this-theorem-regarding-the-sub-gradient-of-p-norm-using-holder-i

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prove this theorem regarding the sub-gradient of p-norm using Holder Inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950226/how-can-i-prove-this-theorem-regarding-the-sub-gradient-of-p-norm-using-holder-i)

Answer (score 2):

Nobody answered me! But I've found the solution finally.
Thanks all!

The inequality can be solved by taking the Holder inequality theorem into account.